# Javascript - Trying to use innerHTML but won't text only changes for a split second

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am new to Javascript and just want to do a simple validation on the username textbox on the below form.

If the username textbox is empty, I want it to print out "Empty" in the span that is next to the textbox when the submit button is clicked. I can get it to do this using the code below but the text only displays for a split second then disappears. Any ideas on how to keep the text there?

```
<form>
    Username: <input type="text" id="username"><span id="val"></span>
    <input type="submit" onclick="check();">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function check() {
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;

        if(username == ""){
            document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Empty";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Full";

        }
    }



</script>
```

Comment: if you don't want to submit the form, why are you using a `submit` input instead of just a button? In fact, you have no reason to use `<form>` elements here.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I just changed the input type to = "button" and it now works as I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the text isn't staying there is because once you click the button it runs the onclick method, but still submits the form. This pretty much resets the form. If you don't want the form to get submitted and reset then you have to stop the form submission as well. If you add a "return false;" line to the javascript method it should stop the form submission and make the text stay.

```
<form>
    Username: <input type="text" id="username"><span id="val"></span>
    <input type="submit" onclick="return check();">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function check() {
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;

        if(username == ""){
            document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Empty";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Full";

        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just tried doing it this way and it is still only showing the text for a split second. I have also tried adding return false directly after the empty and full line and it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: Sorry. The onclick event should include "return". I just edited my post. `onclick="return check();"`

Comment: on a "using markup correctly" note, this should not be a form at all, just get rid of those outer `<form>...</form>` tags. We're not in HTML 3.2 anymore, in modern HTML any `input` element can be used all on its own =) Furthermore, if you need a clickable button, use `<button>`, not an input with type `button` or type `submit`.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that when you have a `<form>` and a submit button, when you click the submit button, it executes the forms action. In this case, it uses the *default* action, and `POST`s to itself essentially. In other words, it reloads the page, passing any info from other form elements on the page to the server in the process.

As suggested in the comments, use a `<button>` and omit the `<form>` alltogether.

```
Username: 
  <input type="text" id="username">
  <span id="val"></span>

<button onclick="check()">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the submit causes the form to be submitted.

If you want the validation to 'fail', you need to return false from the event handler. You can just add 'return false;' after you change the text to empty.